# What could intro_pt_not_on_line be?

Tags: geometry

I am reading [this paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/s9811254/papers/TPHOLs2003.ps) where the authors attempt to translate Hilbert's work on geometry into a computer verified work using Isabelle/Isar. In section 5.2 they illustrate how to computer verifiably prove that there exists a point between any two distinct points. The point of this segment is to stress that Hilbert relied on the geometric intuition too much. They make the following observation:

> Proving this mechanically also required using a lemma called `intro_pt_not_on_line`, which had to show the existence of $AC$.

They do not present what `intro_pt_not_on_line` is. True, they observe that Hilbert would have need to have shown the existence of $AC$, but  I thought that it followed easily from their definition of Axiom 1:

```
AxiomI12: "A≠B ⇒ ∃! a. on_line A a ∧ on_line B a"
```

This does not seem like an blunder in geometric intuition as so much a minor ommision, nor does it *seem* like something that would need an entire lemma. I could not find the complete code, the closest I came to finding the code was [a page on Isabelle projects](http://dream.inf.ed.ac.uk/projects/isabelle/).

My questions is:

Is the point of `intro_pt_not_on_line` simply to show that $A \neq C \implies \exists!AC$? If not, what other things did `intro_pt_not_on_line` show?

Comment: It looks me that "introduction of a point not on ..." has the meaning of introducing a constant's name for a point not lying on the straight line in order to use it further on ; but it must not be that because you call this "a lemma" ...

Comment: @JeanMarie I believe I actually figured it out. I think you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked with one of my professors about this. Although we cannot be entirely sure, it is like `intro_pt_not_on_line` is equivalent to the following statement in English:

> Given two distinct points $A$ and $C$, there exists a point not on $AC$.

Axiom I3 simply says there exists 3 non-colinear points, it does not state given any two distinct points there is a non-colinear points.

However, I believe this result can be derived:

Suppose that we are given two distinct points $A$ and $C$. Suppose otherwise that there does not exist a non-colinear point (1). Then from Axiom I3 we have that there are 3 distinct non-colinear points $D$, $E$, and $F$. But by (1) it must be that $D \in AC$, $E \in AC$, and $F \in AC$. But every two distinct points lie on a distinct line, so $D$, $E$, and $F$ all lie on $AC$ and are all colinear, but this contradicts that $D$, $E$, and $F$ are non-colinear.